# specifying the location for file

Tags: java

I need to give a default location for the user to store the file. like "/Users/username/Desktop". How to give the location for a file? Below code will generate the file in location from where I am running.

```
PrintWriter p = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(tableName + "_insert.sql"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get at the user's home directory with:

```
String directory = System.getProperty("user.home");

// Prefer this over string concatenation to create full filenames
File file = new File(directory, tableName + "_insert.sql");
```

Perhaps go from there?

(Personally I'd avoid using either `PrintWriter` or `FileWriter`, by the way - `PrintWriter` swallows exceptions, and `FileWriter` doesn't let you specify the encoding to use.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the path to the filename:

```
 String yourPath = "/Users/username/Desktop/"; //get that somehow, e.g. by getting the user.dir system property, or hardcode
 PrintWriter p = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(yourPath + tableName + "_insert.sql"));
```